# sum function in Julia is giving error if the array is empty

Tags: julia

I am trying to create a code which identifies if the elements in an array are monotonic or not.

I wrote the below code and got the error -

```
function isMonotonic(array)
    if length(array) <= 2
        return true
    end
    check_up = []
    check_down = []
    for i in range(2, length(array))
        if array[i] <= array[i-1]
            append!(check_up, 1)
        end
        if array[i] >= array[i - 1]
            append!(check_down, 1)
        end
    end
    if sum(check_up) == length(array) - 1 || sum(check_down) == length(array) - 1
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
isMonotonic([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7])
```

I am getting the below error

```
Error: Methoderror: no method matching zero(::Type{Any})
```

I think it is because I am trying to sum up the empth array, I want to understand how to overcome this problem in general, I have a solution for the above code, but in genral I want to know the reason and how to use it. I do not want to first check if the array is empty or not and then do the sum.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you aren't using the built-in `issorted`?

Comment: Even though it's possible to fix your function by changing `[]` to `Int[]`, you should not use this algorithm. First of all, your function iterates through the entire input vector, even after it has become clear it is not monotonic. Even if you have a million elements, starting with [1,2,1, ... million elements], it goes through the whole thing. Secondly, you should not create any vectors while doing this. Just start from the beginning, compare each element to the previous one, and stop if you see the vector is not monotonic. For a million elements, your function is 10 million times slower(!)

Comment: If you think my response has answered your question please feel free to click the tick mark next to it. Otherwise, let me know if you think it can be improved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I am unable to find the tick mark to click. I really liked your approach to identify if the loop breaks the increasing or decreasing order and then stop them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wanted to save yourself lots of effort, the simplest solution would just be:

```
my_ismonotonic(x) = issorted(x) || issorted(x ; rev=true)
```

This will return `true` if `x` is sorted either forwards, or in reverse, and `false` otherwise.

We could maybe make it a little more efficient using a check so we only need a single call to `issorted`.

```
function my_ismonotonic(x)
    length(x) <= 2 && return true
    for n = 2:length(x)
        if x[n] > x[1]
            return issorted(x)
        elseif x[n] < x[1]
            return issorted(x ; rev=true)
        end
    end
    return true
end
# Alternatively, a neater version using findfirst
function my_ismonotonic(x)
    length(x) <= 2 && return true
    ii = findfirst(a -> a != x[1], x)
    isnothing(ii) && return true # All elements in x are equal
    if x[ii] > x[1]
        return issorted(x)
    else
        return issorted(x ; rev=true)
    end
end
```

The loop detects the first occurrence of an element greater than or less than the first element and then calls the appropriate `issorted` as soon as this occurs. If all elements in the array are equal then the loop runs over the whole array and returns `true`.

There are a few problems of efficiency in your approach, but the reason you are getting an actual error message is because given the input, either this expression `sum(check_up)` or this expression `sum(check_down)` will effectively result in the following call:

```
sum(Any[])
```

There is no obvious return value for this since the array could have any type, so instead you get an error. If you had used the following earlier in your function:

```
   check_up = Int[]
   check_down = Int[]
```

then you shouldn't have the same problem, because:

```
julia> sum(Int[])
0
```

Note also that `append!` is usually for appending a vector to a vector. If you just want to add a single element to a vector use `push!`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, really appreciate it

Comment: I kind of understand the below line, but have not seen anyone using it before, can you please explain a bit more

Comment: length(x) <= 2 && return true

Comment: @Harneet.Lamba Sure. `length(x) <= 2` returns a `Bool` of `true` if `x` has `2` or less elements, and `false` otherwise. The `&&` is the "and" operator. We only move past it if the condition immediately before it evaluates to `true`. Then `return true` will exit the function returning the value `true`. So in plain English, the whole line evaluates to: "if `x` has less than or equal to `2` elements then exit the function returning the value `true`, otherwise continue on in the function".